# Angular - setValue() of array of formGroups sets last object for whole formArray value

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form like this with an array of form groups `objform`.

```
this.objform = this.fb.group({
  val: null,
  string: '',
  arr: this.fb.array([null, null, null])
})
this.nestedform = this.fb.group({
  arr: this.fb.array([this.objform, this.objform, this.objform]),
  test1: null,
  test2: ""
})
```

I have ran into a problem that when I setValue() of `this.nestedform`, the value of `arr` is the last obj in my array over and over. Why is this happening? And am I just making some silly mistake?

Thanks

P.S.
I have a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byvafx) if you want to see the full example.

Comment: how are you binding this in your template?

Comment: moving nestedform to first will solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're asingning the **same** object to the array in nestedForm. Use a function that return a formGroup

```
  getGroup()
  {
    return this.fb.group({
      val: null,
      str: '',
      arr: this.fb.array([null, null, null])
    })
  }
```

And use when create the form

```
this.nestedform = this.fb.group({
  arr: this.fb.array([this.getGroup(), this.getGroup(), this.getGroup()]),
  test1: null,
  test2: ""
})
```

So, you has a different "objects"